# Inputs not triggering if statments in python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I've been working on a python old-shool computer system for fun but when I run the code the inputs don't trigger the next line of code. This is the code:

```
correctPassword = "testpassword"
guess = ""
guesses = ""
query = ""
run = 1
datacmd = ""
newfilename = ""
newtext = ""
filename = ""
appendtext = ""
helpcmd = ""
helpdcmd = ""
gameselect = ""
import time
import random
import datetime

while guess != correctPassword:
    guess = input("Password: ")

print ("loging in")

time.sleep(5)
print("Login complete.")
time.sleep(0.5)

while query == "":
    input("Please select one of the following queries by typing it into the box. data, helpme, games, date, close.")
    query = input
    #data section. read, write and edit files here
if query == "data":
        print("Welcome to data. For information on how to use your data section visit the help page.")
        input("command:")
```

The specific lines are the if query lines. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python input tutorial", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do `query = input` like that. It has to be `query = input("Please select...")`. It should match `guess = input("Password: ")` above.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help! I greatly appreciate it :)